# how to set hex colour as the background for my window in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, hex, window

I have been trying to figure out why this has been happening when I try to access my hex colour as the background color in window, searched for the solution everywhere but didn't got the exact one.
It is throwing -> `tkinter.TclError: unknown color name 'f7f5dd'`.
Please guide me the way :

```
    from tkinter import *
    YELLOW = "f7f5dd"
    window = Tk()
    window.minsize(width=400, height=300)
    window.title("Pomodoro App")
    window.config(padx=100, pady=50,bg=YELLOW)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the hash symbol/number-sign to the front of the color string.

```
from tkinter import *
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=400, height=300)
window.title("Pomodoro App")
window.config(padx=100, pady=50,bg=YELLOW)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.config`. You can use this. Add symbol `#` in front of color string.

```
from tkinter import *
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
window = Tk()
window.minsize(width=400, height=300)
window.title("Pomodoro App")
window['background']=YELLOW
window.mainloop()
```